# Value Error in Python when converting string to date using datetime.strptime

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

I have a string variable named dte that prints in the following format:

```
Tue Feb 13 23:49:10 +0000 2018
```

I'm trying to convert it to a date type so that I can work out how long ago it was in days, hours, minutes etc but keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Tue Feb 13 23:49:10 +0000 2018' does not match format '%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %z %Y'
```

I'm using this code:

```
new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dte, "%a %b %d %I:%M:%S %z %Y")
print(new_date)
```

I've tried removing the colons but get the same error. I'm sure it's something very simple I'm overlooking but can't figure out what it is.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `%H` for the hour component not `%I`:

```
In[8]:
dte="Tue Feb 13 23:49:10 +0000 2018"
new_date = dt.datetime.strptime(dte, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
new_date

Out[8]: datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 13, 23, 49, 10, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

You have 24-hour hour component, not 12-hour which is what `%I` is for, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)